# Ayuda Bucles Python

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo a usar python y hay una cosa que no consigo hacerla, quiero hacer un bucle para cuando formulo una pregunta solo me deje poner una de estas letras `a, b, c, d, e` eso en la primera tirada, después de eso me vuelve a preguntar que letra quiero escoger, pero ahora puedo escoger 5 más es decir `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j` y en la próxima tirada 5 letras más y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a 25 letras.

Os pego abajo lo que tengo hecho, funciona medio bien no deja poner números ni las otras letras, el problema es cuando pongo dos letras (por ejemplo `hj`) me peta si me pudieseis ayudar o hacerlo de alguna otra forma que funcionase os lo agradecería.

```
cuantas_frutas_coger = 5
letra = 97 #Es la letra a en ASCII
jugador = '1'
while not jugador.isalpha() or ord(jugador) > letra+cuantas_frutas_coger:
    print ('Elige una letra entre a y ', chr(letra+cuantas_frutas_coger))
    jugador = input('')
```

No sé si me he explicado bien, es un juego en el que primero tienes que coger 5 letras, si ganas hay 10, si vuelves a ganar 15 y solo me falta ese trozo.
Gracias.

Comment: y nunca cambias el valor de frutas a coger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respecto a la lectura de datos, puedes hacer una de estas dos cosas.

1. Tomar sólo la primera letra de la respuesta del jugador. Así, si escribe "aj", la "j" se descartaría:

   ```
   while not jugador.isalpha() or ord(jugador) > letra+cuantas_frutas_coger:
       print ('Elige una letra entre a y ', chr(letra+cuantas_frutas_coger))
       jugador = input('')
       jugador = jugador[0]
   ```
2. No dar por válida una entrada que tenga varias letras, y obligar al jugador a repetir la entrada si pone más de una:

   ```
   while (len(jugador) > 1 or
          not jugador.isalpha() or
          ord(jugador) > letra+cuantas_frutas_coger):
       print ('Elige una letra entre a y ', chr(letra+cuantas_frutas_coger))
       jugador = input('')
       jugador = jugador[0]
   ```

En cuanto a cómo sigue el juego, no me ha quedado claro. Supongo que esta entrada de datos debería estar formando parte de otro bucle en el que se vaya incrementando la variable `cuantas_frutas_coger` pero no entiendo bien con qué criterio. En todo caso tu pregunta se limitaba a la entrada de datos ¿no?

Comment: Sii, muchas gracias por la respuesta, va perfecta. Bueno es un juego de estos de memoria que te salen 5 nombres y luego te pregunta que nombre era el que estaba en la posición tal y si lo adivinas pues en vez de salir 5 te salen 10 y así van sumando. Gracias por todo